# Do we have closures in C++?

Tags: c++, closures, lexical-closures

I was reading about closures on the net. I was wondering if C++ has a built-in facility for closures or if there is any way we can implement closures in C++?

Comment: Besides the answer below, also check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for more of a reference page.

Comment: Apparently lots of people still mix anonymous functions with closures. It is still not clear for me if C++11 indeed supports closures, or just anonymous functions ("lambdas"). I would _not_ expect C++ to support actual closures in the same sense as in JavaScript, Python, Scala and others, would find it very surprising.

Comment: Proving myself wrong, yeah, it captures variables in context, by copy and even by reference apparently, the only quirk is that there is no garbage collection... Still would like to better understand how that all works in practice http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.nl/2013/05/lambdas-vs-closures.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The latest C++ standard, [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), has closures.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions

http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Comment: No we don't. In C++, all closures are member functions of a hidden class that gets passed around. And because a class gets passed around, the function singnatures are incompatible. Yes, we kinda have closures, but they are NOT actual closures, they are NOT a function that has access to some other functions variables, that gets allocated and whose address can be passed around. Neither with bind, nor with lambda-expressions. And Visual Studio/VisualCPP doesn't support alloc_callback, which is used in C to do this. And you can't pass a member function to a function that expects a static function.

Comment: @StefanSteiger I guess Rust closures aren't actual closures either then? They're exactly like that. Do the C++11 implement some interface so they can be called dynamically, similarly to `dyn Fn(x) -> y`  in Rust?

Answer (score 26):

If you understand closure as a reference to a function that has an embedded, persistent, hidden and unseparable context (memory, state), then yes:

```
class add_offset {
private:
    int offset;
public:
    add_offset(int _offset) : offset(_offset) {}
    int operator () (int x) { return x + offset; }
}

// make a closure
add_offset my_add_3_closure(3);

// use closure
int x = 4;
int y = my_add_3_closure(x);
std::cout << y << std::endl;
```

The next one modifies its state:

```
class summer
{
private:
    int sum;
public:
    summer() : sum(0) {}
    int operator () (int x) { return sum += x; }
}

// make a closure
summer adder;
// use closure
adder(3);
adder(4);
std::cout << adder(0) << std::endl;
```

The inner state can not be referenced (accessed) from outside.

Depending on how you define it, a closure can contain a reference to more than one function or, two closures can share the same context, i.e. two functions can share the same persistent state.

Closure means not containing free variables - it is comparable to a class with only private attributes and only public method(s).

Comment: The behavior is similar to a closure but I would not say it is a closure.

Comment: @Stepenre what would be the difference?

Comment: This hardly looks like a closure, what you have here is just an object holding a state modified by a method, plus some syntactic sugar due to the fact it is "operator()" instead of any other method. Make it return a lambda that depends on the state, or on a parameter of the method, and then we are talking.

Comment: @dividebyzero One thing is the abstract idea of a closure, another thing is how you use that idea in a programming language. In the examples above, both "my_add_3_closure" and "adder" are closures - they match the definition. The objects here is effectively a references to a function... I want to underline that the idea of closures was used in C++ programming long before C++11 and that the new lambda construct just makes it easier.

Comment: @Zrin I'd like to comment that other instances of `summer` will have access to each other's private `sum` variable, as access keywords in C++ are per-class, not per-instance. Because of this I'd argue it is not a closure (as encapsulation is a property many people expect). Lambdas on the other hand do not break this encapsulation, as each has a unique type.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa, you're making a mistake in your argument. `private: int sum` means the member can be accessed only by member functions, but it still belongs to the instance, not to the class. `static int sum` would belong to the class.

Comment: @Zrin. Consider the following code. Running it will show what I mean (and sorry, the formatting in a comment will be terrible I'm sure): ```class X {
    int x;

    public:
        X(int x): x(x)  { }

        int getX(const X& instance) const {
            return instance.x;
        }

        void setX(X& instance, const int newX) {
            instance.x = newX;
        }
};

int main() {
    X a(0);
    X b(1);

    // Read access
    std::cout << a.getX(b) << std::endl;

    // Write access
    a.setX(b, 2);

    std::cout << b.getX(b) << std::endl;
}```

Comment: @Zrin as you can see, if you run that snippet in [this online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), that a's instance methods can manipulate b's private members. `public`, `private`, and `protected` are compile-time guarantees and are on a per-class basis, not per-instance.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa, your critique of the examples I've given in the answer above is that the closure's context is not hidden well enough, because there is nothing that would stop an ignorant programmer to deliberately and obviously break the concept. But if the creator doesn't want a closure, then why bother anyway?

Comment: @Zrin I was just pointing out a technical detail. Functionally it's good enough.

Comment: For anyone who thinks this isn't a closure. Functionally, this is definitely a closure. It might not look like a closure compared to one's personal experience. But the visual looks of what one considers a closure is entirely a personal opinion and isn't really definable. At the end of the day, all that really matters if the functionality.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, This shows how you could implement a function with a state without using a functor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
 
std::function<int()> make_my_closure(int x) {
    return [x]() mutable {   
        ++x;
        return x;   
    };
}

int main()  {
    auto my_f = make_my_closure(10);
    
    std::cout << my_f() << std::endl; // 11
    std::cout << my_f() << std::endl; // 12
    std::cout << my_f() << std::endl; // 13
    
     auto my_f1 = make_my_closure(1);

    std::cout << my_f1() << std::endl; // 2
    std::cout << my_f1() << std::endl; // 3
    std::cout << my_f1() << std::endl; // 4

    std::cout << my_f() << std::endl; // 14
}
```

Comment: To be really sure, it would be nice to see what happens if you run `my_f()` again after `my_f1()`, because it might still be the same variable that you have just directly assigned with the call to `make_my_closure`.

Comment: `x` is a temporary value in `make_my_closure`.
So IMO it would not make sense. I added the case you asked.
Which behave as expected

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that it depends on what you mean by closure.  The meaning I've
always used implies garbage collection of some sort (although I think it
could be implemented using reference counting); unlike lambdas in other
languages, which capture references and keep the referenced object
alive, C++ lambdas either capture a value, or the object refered to is
*not* kept alive (and the reference can easily dangle).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, C++11 has closures named [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

In C++03 there is no built-in support for lambdas, but there is [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/lambda/) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking. 'Closure' is LISP only. Use Let returns lambda as last commands. 'Let Over Lambda'. This is possible only for LISP because of infinite scope with lexical scoping. I don't know any other language support this natively until know.

```
(defun my-closure ()
   (let ((cnt 0))
      (lambda () 
         (format t "called : ~A times" (incf cnt)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive similar functionality using static variables and lambdas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<std::function<int()>()> generator_function=[]()->std::function<int()>{
        static int i=0;
        return [&]()->int{
            return i++;
        };
    };
    
    std::function<int()> iterator_function=generator_function();
    
    std::cout<<iterator_function()<<std::endl;  //1
    std::cout<<iterator_function()<<std::endl;  //2
    std::cout<<iterator_function()<<std::endl;  //3 
    std::cout<<iterator_function()<<std::endl;  //4
    return 0;
}
```