# C++: How to pass a function+arguments as parameter without executing it?

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

I have 3 algorithms function:

```
void algo1(int para1, int para2);
void algo2(int para1, int para2);
void algo3(int para1, int para2);
```

and I want set a timer to test these functions' efficiency

```
int get_execute_time( void(*f)(int para1, int para2) );
```

I pass the function as parameter to `get_execute_time` to avoid abundance, however, the problem is I also need to pass the arguments, which is `para1`, `para2`.

so I let timer function change to

```
get_execute_time( void(*f)(int para1, int para2) , 
                 int para1, int para2) {
    (*f)(para1, para2); // call it
}
```

and, the code above seems ugly to me, **so is there any option to wrap the code and let the code execute later in C++?**

so that I can do like this:

```
// definition
get_execute_time(this_code_will_execute_later) {
    this_code_will_execute_later();
};
// usage
get_execute_time(algo1(para1, para2));
```

**Temporary solution**: utilize `class` to implement `closure-like` thing( inspired from [Do we have closures in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464436/8832133)

```
class timer {
private:
    int para1;
    int para2;
public:
    timer(int para1, int para2);
    operator () (void(*f)(int para1, int para2)) { (*f)(para1, para2) }
}
// thus we can write these following code
timer timer(para1, para2);
std::cout << "run " << timer(algo1) << " ms";
std::cout << "run " << timer(algo2) << " ms"
std::cout << "run " << timer(algo3) << " ms"
```

So, Do exist better options? Thanks anyway!

Comment: You may use a lambda and capture some values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with either [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or via a lambda.  For example (just one parameter shown for brevity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void get_execute_time (std::function <void (void)> f)
{
    f ();
}

void foo (int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int param = 42;
    auto f1 = std::bind (foo, param);
    get_execute_time (f1);

    ++param;
    auto f2 = [param] { foo (param); };
    get_execute_time (f2);
}
```

Output:

```
42
43
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zjIQW72TSYmTCAIn)